# Dropping postgres role and database after many grants

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql, database-administration

I'm trying to efficiently `drop role` from a postgres instance, and running into some problems. I'm looking for some SQL to `drop role` so that I can stop reading error messages and don't have to do this manually.

In the setup I'm working in, every roles gets its own database of the same name:

```
CREATE ROLE alpha_user;
CREATE DATABASE alpha_user;
ALTER DATABASE alpha_user OWNER TO alpha_user;
```

Users often grant access to schemas in their database to other users:

```
-- alpha_user logs in to the alpha_user database
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA myschema TO beta_user;
```

When I attempt to drop `beta_user`, this happens:

```
-- log in as superuser
DROP ROLE beta_user;
-- ERROR:  role "beta_user" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
-- DETAIL:  N objects in database alpha_user
```

I can connect to the `alpha_user` database, and drop `OWNED BY`, but this is inefficient:

```
-- log in as superuser
\c alpha_user;
DROP OWNED BY beta_user CASCADE;
DROP beta_user;
-- success
```

Users can grant access to any number of databases, and there are many users. Is there a statement (or series of statements) that a super user can execute to `DROP OWNED BY` for a user across all databases where the user has been granted access?

Comment: What's your version of PostgreSQL and what's your operating system ?

Comment: Postgres 9.4, and Ubuntu 14.04. Why should operating system matter?

Comment: You could use the help of the command line tools that linux provides.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you:

```
with 
  user_id as (select oid, rolname as my_user from pg_authid where rolname in('abc', 'xyz'))
select 'REVOKE ' || rolname || ' FROM ' || my_user || ' CASCADE;' as sql
from pg_auth_members
join pg_authid on pg_auth_members.roleid = pg_authid.oid  
JOIN user_id ON pg_auth_members.member = user_id.oid
union 
SELECT 'REVOKE ALL ON ' || datname || ' FROM ' || my_user || ' CASCADE;' 
FROM pg_database 
JOIN user_id ON pg_database.datdba = user_id.oid
```